# Which individual Superhero role has been portrayed by the highest number of individuals?

Tags: super-hero, secret-identity

In a single fantasy universe, which Superhero character has had the most individuals portray themselves as being(secretly temporally substituting for) the Superhero, or  have actually taken over the role of the Superhero?

For instance, Alfred sometimes donned the cape and cowl and was seen as Batman.

Comment: Do legacy heroes count? For example, there have been multiple Flashes over the years, with them not pretending to be a different person, just different people donning the mantle.

Comment: I would like a Superhero that seamlessly blends. If a legacy character can pull that off, then yes. But if it's  publicly known another person has taken over, no. That's not the answer I was looking for. :)

Comment: There's been a bunch of supermen but I'm guessing someone will come up with a clever answer based on some superhero meeting his clones

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LegacyCharacter

Comment: Does the finale of [V for Vendetta](http://thdirectorschair.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/936full-v-for-vendetta-screenshot.jpg) count?

Comment: @philipp - You should make that an answer so I can upvote it again

Comment: I wonder, how many Robin sidekicks did Batman have?

Comment: As predicted, two of the answers have already referenced cloning events; Agent Smith, The Master, etc. The question isn't sufficiently clear.

Comment: @b_jonas: There are 3, one of them die, the second become Nightwing, and the third is still Robin.

Comment: I'm not clear as to how this question is unclear. I would like to know which Superheroes shoes have been filled by other individual people more often than anybody elses has. No. Clones shouldn't count, and Mr. Smith was not a hero. He(it) was a program.

Comment: @Richard - Agent Elrond... errr... Agent Smith, is NOT a superhero by any stretch of imagination. Neither is V as far as I'm concerned, though I can see how someone can quibble on that one. And even if he is, people wearing a mask to LOOK like him isn't the same as acting as that superhero

Comment: V is definitely a superhero. Super powers? Check. Does heroic things? Check.

Comment: @Richard Super-Goofy and Super-Duck have super-powers, they does heroic things, but are Mickey Mouse's sidekicks superheros?

Comment: @oak - bluntly, yes.

Comment: @Richard What exactly are V's super powers? I don't count Olympic-level reflexes, a genius intellect, or proficiency with swords and martial arts as super powers, since many non-super humans have those.

Comment: @TylerH - In the film canon, his martial artistry goes well beyond anything a human (Olympian or not) could realistically achieve. In the comics, we're more led to believe that his hyper-agility and speed are a function of his "inner censor" being removed. Either way, he jumps and whirls like a dervish and throws knives at distances that defy belief.

Comment: @DrakaSAN There have been 5 Robins in the main DC continuity. 2 have died, 1 has been brought back to life, and one has faked her death (yes that's right *her*)  1.Dick Grayson, 2.Jason Todd (died, but brought back to life) 3.Tim Drake, 4.Stephanie Brown, 5. Damien Wayne (currently dead)

Comment: I think the real question we must ask ourselves here is...

Does Sparticus count?

Comment: @Monty129: Oops, should have continued to read Batman, thanks for the info : ), didn t known Stephanie Brown.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [Phantom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Phantom) is a hero identity passed down from father to son since 1536, when (according to Wikipedia) the father of British sailor Christopher Walker was killed during a pirate attack. Swearing an oath on the skull of his father's murderer to fight evil, Christopher started the legacy of the Phantom that would be passed from father to son.  There have been 22 Phantoms.

Comment: True dat! The Phantom is a legacy hero passed down throughout the ages and eventually landing on the shoulders of [Billy Zane](http://www.zuguide.com/images/3628/3628.0.570.359.jpg) ;]

Comment: Actually, the Phantom of 2040 is the last Phantom in the timeline of the canon. He is the 24th Phantom in the line.

Answer (score 12):

The movie [V for Vendetta](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0434409/) ends with a protest march of *several hundred* people portraying the titular protagonist V.

Due to being the involuntary subject of a government experiment, V has certain superhuman abilities so he definitely qualifies as *super*. But whether or not he also qualifies as a *hero* is a matter of debate.

Comment: In the case of V, several hundred people dress up as V, but none believe that all of the others *are* V.

Comment: @MajorStackings - I think they're all under the impression that at least one of their number is V.

Comment: I interpret the ending as conveying the message "V is not a person, V is a symbol. Everyone can be this symbol. Everyone can be V"

Comment: Yup.  All you have to do is buy a WB Officially Licensed "Guy Fawkes" mask.

Answer (score 3):

Along the lines of The Phantom, in the Marvel world, there is also [Black Panther](http://marvel.wikia.com/Black_Panther). Unfortunately, I don't know the exact history of how long that mantle has been past, but it's another hereditary role that has been passed through the royal line of Wakanda for centuries.

Answer (score 3):

I'd nominate Green Lantern. Not only the short list of *human* Green Lanterns, but the entire Green Lantern Corps. They aren't really individual super heroes, they are members of a universal police force. According to [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern_Corps), there are 3600 *active* GLs at a time.

Comment: I don't think this applies as only one would be 'that Green Lantern from Earth that gets his own comic'.  There are many green lanterns, but only one Green Lantern.  Just like there are many sergeants, but only one Sergeant Fury.

Comment: But there's more than one Howlin' Commando. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think **Batman** easily tops the **Phantom**. In the Nolan Trilogy Imposters are only mentioned shortly, but there's also the whole *"I am Batman" movement* going an - I don't think they ever mention the exact numbers or anything unfortunately.

Also, if you expand *superhero* and make it *being with superhuman feats*, then the **Master** from **Doctor Who** might qualify as well. He created like **7 billion copies** of himself in **The End of Time** (called those new humans the [**Master Race**](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Master_Race)). It's only hinted at, but he most likely transformed dead bodies as well, making the number even bigger. It's not obvious whether they just share appearance or abilities as well though. They don't really take over his role though, also he considers them all being "us", himself included.

Comment: Wow! 7 billion sounds much more than Agent Smith had ever achieved.

Comment: But they weren't "portraying" the Master, they were all the same person.

Comment: @b-jonas - Indeed. The population of the Matrix was probably about 6 billion.

Comment: @Richard Yes, although we don't know how perfect that copy's been made, like indeed two hearts and stuff or just similar appearance (compare it to the *Chameleon Arch*, which changed the body, but not appearance - but that might have been just for the audience as well).